# You have to be inside an ember-cli project in order to use the serve command

Tags: ember-cli

I done a git clone of ember-cli, and then done this:

```
cd ember-cli
npm link ember-cli
ember server
```

but get

```
You have to be inside an ember-cli project in order to use the serve command.
```

any ideas?

EDIT___________________________________________

I got round this by just reinstalling it again.

Answer (score 5):

While you are inside *the* ember-cli directory, you are not inside of an actual ember-cli project which is why `ember server` does not work.  I'm not sure what you are trying to do, but if you are trying to create an ember-cli project you can do these commands outside of that ember-cli directory:

```
ember new foo
cd foo
npm link ember-cli
ember server
```

Comment: ok thanks, I just wanted to use the latest source on github but apparently I have to create it via the ember-cli tool

Comment: You are on the right track for using the master version of ember-cli, just keep following the steps in the project's readme and you should be good.

Comment: it doesn't work 
A:\WebstormProjects\ember-cli>npm link ember-
cli
**A:\WebstormProjects\ember-cli\node_modules\em
ber-cli -> C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ember-cli -> C:\Users
\me\Downloads\t\ember-cli**

Comment: Did you ever do `ember new project`?  It seems like you are still trying to run an ember server in the ember-cli source code directory instead of in an ember-cli project.

Comment: I done a new ember project and it worked but when I did an upgrade following the steps I get the same error when I try run it. I deleted the fit folder though.

Comment: the .git folder has no effect. this cli stuff just seems to fragile atm

Comment: It's still not all the clear what you are trying to accomplish here

Answer (score 1):

If you use app name as `ember-cli`, `emberCli`, you will get this error. These words are reserved words.